# Replace xml node attribute with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have to replace an XML node attribute value using a batch file, XSLT and other methods are not an option.

Node attribute to find:
    `add key="RemEnabled" value="true" />`

To be replaced with:
    `add key="RemEnabled" value="false" />`

I am struggling with the fact there are quotes, what I have so far is:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set txtfile=x.config
set newfile=xnew.config
if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
set newline=%%a 
set newline=!newline:^"RemEnabled^" value=^"true^"=^"RemEnabled^" value=^"false^"!
echo !newline! >> %newfile%
)
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
type file.xml|repl "(.*add key=\x22RemEnabled\x22 value=\x22)true(\x22 \/>.*)" "$1false$2" >file2.xml
```